# Conexión de tabla Visual Fox Pro (.dbf) y php

Tags: php, sql, odbc, visual-foxpro

Voy directo al grano.

Estoy trabajando en un sistema web y me pidieron acceder a la base de datos del sistema que usa la empresa, el problema es que ellos usan un sistema basado en Visual Fox Pro y necesito acceder a los datos de una tabla en específico. He leído miles foros más no encuentro algún resultado, el error que me arroja siempre es este:

`Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicaci�n., SQL state IM014 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemaJRMVC\a.php on line 6 Error al conectar: [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicaci�n.`

Uso la version 8.2 de PHP, es muy reciente, entonces no sé si odbc aún funciona en este caso, estoy intentando con adodb, pero es casi lo mismo. Mi DNS está configurada así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi código php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\Users\practicante\Desktop\facturacion\envios.DBF;Exclusive=No';
$usuario = "";
$contrasena = "";

$conexion = odbc_connect($dsn, $usuario, $contrasena);

if (!$conexion) {
    die("Error en la conexión: " . odbc_errormsg());
} else {
    echo "Conexión exitosa a la base de datos.";   
}
?>
```

Alguna ayuda o algo que me puedan proporcionar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tal vez tu error pudiera estar dado porque creas un DSN sobre arquitectura de 64 bits con un conector de 32 bits??? VFP está descontinuado, quizas ADODb pudiera ayudar (tiene soporte para PHP8.2, aunque para VFP exactamente ni idea si lo mantienen aun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras mucho tiempo investigando e intentando, no logré usar ni ADODB como se me sugirió en el comentario, tampoco ODBC. Mi solución fue un poco ¿"complicada"?, lo que hice fue crear un script en Python, aquí el código:

```
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(event.src_path, "modificado.")
        ruta_tabla_dbf = "envios.dbf"
        ruta_archivo_csv = "csvDates/MiTabla.csv"
        self.convertir_dbf_a_csv(ruta_tabla_dbf, ruta_archivo_csv)

    def convertir_dbf_a_csv(self, ruta_dbf, ruta_csv):
        with DBF(ruta_dbf) as dbf_table:
            df = pd.DataFrame(iter(dbf_table))
            df.to_csv(ruta_csv, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyEventHandler(), ".", recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while observer.is_alive():
            observer.join(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Que su función es observar la actividad en la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo .dbf y tras alguna modificación de cualquier archivo de dicha carpeta crea un archivo .csv de la tabla VFP. Así logro que a cualquier ingreso de dato que se haga a la tabla, se modifique en tiempo real el archivo .csv.

Con eso logrado (la obtención de datos en tiempo real de la tabla .dbf), pude crear un código en php que lee el archivo .csv creado, el código es este:

```
<?php

function obtenerDatosEspecificosPorId($archivoCSV, $idBuscar) {
    $archivo = fopen($archivoCSV, 'r');

    // Array para almacenar los resultados
    $resultados = [];

    while (($fila = fgetcsv($archivo)) !== false) {
        // Verificar si el ID coincide
        if ($fila[4] == $idBuscar) {
            // Seleccionar las columnas específicas
            $resultados = [
                "noGuia" => $fila[4],
                "usuario" => $fila[39],
                "dirDest" => $fila[32],
                "nombreDest" => $fila[31],
                "numeroCE" => $fila[62],
            ];
            // No es necesario seguir buscando, ya encontramos la fila deseada
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose($archivo);
    return $resultados;
}

// Indicamos el archivo csv en el que están los datos
$archivoCSV = 'csvDates/MiTabla.csv';
$idBuscar = $_POST['noGuia'];
$datosObtenidos = obtenerDatosEspecificosPorId($archivoCSV, $idBuscar);

// Imprimimos el resultado
echo json_encode($datosObtenidos);
?>
```

Que, pues, ya es la lógica que necesitaba para mi aplicación. La lógica se basa en enviar un id por `$_POST` y a base de ese id, devolverme las columnas que necesito mostrar.

Repito, es algo que quizás no sea muy práctico, pero tomando en cuenta que VFP ya es una tecnología discontinuada y muy vieja, no lo veo tan mal como una posible alternativa. Espero ayude a más de alguien esta idea.